# Non blocking kernel launches in OpenCL intel implementation

Tags: opencl

I have the following skeleton code

```
ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL,
            &global_item_size,NULL,0, NULL, NULL);

printf("print immediately\n ");
```

I thought and read somewhere that clEnqueueNDRangeKernel is non blocking call and cpu continues its execution immediately after enqueuing the kernel.

But I see a different behaviour. printf statement executes after kernel completes execution. Why am I seeing this behaviour?. How to make any kernel calls non blocking?.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel()` is supposed to be non-blocking. However, the code you show does not allow to definitively conclude that the kernel finishes before the `printf` statement. There's several possibilities:

- The kernel is not enqueued properly or fails to run. You need to check if the return value `ret` is `CL_SUCCESS`, and if not, fix whatever needs to be fixed and try again.
- The kernel runs fast and the thread on which the kernel runs is likely to be given priority, such that the `printf` statement ends up being executed after the kernel finishes.
- The kernel is actually running during the `printf` statement, since nothing in your code allows you to conclude otherwise. To check if the kernel is running or finished, you need to use an event. For example:

```c
cl_event evt = NULL;
cl_int ret, evt_status;
// ...
ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL,
            &global_item_size, NULL, 0, NULL, &evt);
// Check if it's finished or not
if (ret == CL_SUCCESS)
{
    clGetEventInfo(evt, CL_EVENT_COMMAND_EXECUTION_STATUS,
             sizeof(cl_int), (void*) &evt_status, NULL);
    if (evt_status == CL_COMPLETE)
        printf("Kernel is finished\n");
    else
        printf("Kernel is NOT finished\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Something's wrong: %d\n", ret);
}
```